# Need to redirect php page to html using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect .php page to .html. My url is like `http://localhost/lions/contacts.php` and I need to rewrite like `http://localhost/lions/contacts.html` using htaccess.

Till Now I've used following code:

```
RewriteRule . %1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.html$ index.php
```

But its not working. Please help thanks.

My Complete htaccess file looks like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /lions/

#redirect localhost/lions/page.php?page_id=1&album_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/lions/1/1/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&album_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&album_id=$2&action=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/lions/page.php?page_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/lions/1/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/lions/contacts.php to localhost/lions/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/lions/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /lions/

#redirect localhost/lions/page.php?page_id=1&album_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/lions/1/1/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&album_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1/%2/%3.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&album_id=$2&action=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/lions/page.php?page_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/lions/1/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/lions/contacts.php to localhost/lions/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule !^admin/ /%1.html [NC,R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hello Anubhava, previously you helped me for rewrite url using htaccess and its working perfect but now in the same project I need the same rule I mean I just need to replace .php with .html extension. Like previously you helped me to rewrite rule for two parameters and three but now there is no parameter only file with php extension. Your provided solution doesn't help it redirects to me to localhost/lions/.html with no file found server error

Comment: I've updated my question, please check its redirecting to correct url but it got server error requested url not found and also my other rules are not working either

Comment: I think rewrite base is creating problem when I go to localhost/lions/contacts.php then it redirects to localhost/lions/lions/contact.html and if I remove rewrite base then contact url works but not other url

Comment: Yeah its working fine thanks a lot, you are really a genius in regx and htaccess

Comment: But still last problem I have admin also for the same url like localhost/lions/admin/dashboard.php and its redirect to localhost/lions/admin/dashboard.html but I don't want to change url for admin section so how to restrict it for admin url

Comment: Hello Anubhava, Please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508079/need-to-correct-htaccess-to-restrict-some-folder I am sure you can help me in this