# Need to correct htaccess to restrict some folder

Tags: .htaccess

I am using following htaccess code in my project

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /apnaujjain

#redirect localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=1&album_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/apnaujjain/1/1/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&album_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&album_id=$2&action=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/apnaujjain/1/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/apnaujjain/contacts.php to localhost/apnaujjain/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule !^admin/ /%1.html [NC,R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php\s [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [R=302,L,NE]
#RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Now everything is working fine except one thing I have some webservice also that I am calling from webservice folder, url is

```
http://localhost/apnaujjain/webservice/gethomepagecontent1.php
```

Now the problem is due to htaccess my webservice stopped working, it redirecting to wrong page so its not working. I don't want to apply htaccess rule on webservice folder. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just below `RewriteBase /apnaujjain` line add this line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apnaujjain/

# add everything for webservice/...
RewriteRule ^webservice(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]

# rest of your existing rules
```

Comment: thanks its working now but one more question in future we will have blog on this site so its url will be like http://localhost/apnaujjain/blog.php?page_id=13&action=blog and http://localhost/apnaujjain/blog.php?page_id=13&post_id=1&action=blog, I also need to change these url in html format so rules will be same or will change, please guide me

Comment: I believe above rules should still work as long `/blog.php` has same query parameters.

Comment: Hello Anubhava, please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959547/need-to-write-multiplae-htaccess-rule-with-multiple-parameters as you told me that same rule will work for blog.php page but its not working, please help...