# Need to write multiple htaccess rule with multiple parameters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've some rules already written in htaccess to convert .php extension to HTML and they are working fine but now I need to write rule for different page with same parameter but it if I set same rule for different page its not working its redirecting on same page.

Below is my htaccess file code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /apnaujjain/

# add everything for webservice/...
RewriteRule ^webservice(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]

#redirect localhost/apnaujjain/blog.php?page_id=1&post_id=1&action=blog to localhost/apnaujjain/1/1/blog.html

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&album_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
#RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3.html? [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ blog.php?page_id=$1&album_id=$2&action=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=1&album_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/apnaujjain/1/1/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&album_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&album_id=$2&action=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/apnaujjain/1/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/apnaujjain/contacts.php to localhost/apnaujjain/contacts.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php\s [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(admin|webservice)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule !^admin/ /%1.html [NC,R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

I have already written comment on every rule for what its doing. Now currently all rules are working but when I added other rule it stopped working so I just commented that rule.

Rule for `page.php` is working but when I change page to `blog.php` some rules work but some rule with multiple parameter with `blog.php` doesn't work.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: This won't be possible actually since pretty URI schemes for `blog.php` and `page.php` are similar now.

Comment: So can't we force url to redirect where we want or make it static like if page.php comes so it redirects to page.php and blog.php to blog.php or I can change the parameter name in blog.php (page_id to page) so it will work or not?

Comment: Hello Anubhava, please help its last thing that needs to work every url is working correct now just need to change http://localhost/apnaujjain/blog_detail.php?post_id=1&action=blog to http://localhost/apnaujjain/1/blog, please help its urgent I am unable to get it solved, please reply fast....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to route `localhost/apnaujjain/1/blog` to `http://localhost/apnaujjain/blog_detail.php?post_id=1&action=blog`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog_detail\.php\?post_id(\d+)&action=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2.html? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(blog)\.html$ blog_detail.php?post_id=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry but this rule is not working and one more thing if want to redirect at http://localhost/apnaujjain/1/blog.html then how to do it?

Comment: I removed all other rules and then try your suggested rule but still its not working, actually nothing is redirecting just showing blog_detail page, I think redirection is not working now I don't know why.

Comment: Ok sorry for misunderstanding actually I need when I enter http://localhost/apnaujjain/blog_detail.php?post_id=1&action=blog then it should redirect to http://localhost/apnaujjain/1/blog.html

Comment: Hello Anubhava, I've again an issue regarding htaccess in codeigniter. Please look into this question stackoverflow.com/questions/31043274, I am sure you can help me in this

Comment: Hello Anubhava, Sorry to disturb you but I again I stuck in .htaccess file. Please look into this question. Its really urgent. Please when you get time just look into this issue. Thanks in advance. url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913023/sub-domain-url-is-not-working

Comment: Hello Anubhava, I am again stuck in .htaccess file. Please look into this question if you get time. I know I am disturbing you again but its urgent and I am not getting any response and you helped me a lot. So I thought this time you can also help me. The quetion url is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579980/need-to-redirect-folders-like-sub-domain-within-same-domain-using-htaccess?noredirect=1#comment54937032_33579980

Comment: OK I am on mobile at present, will check the question once I get back to my computer.