# Sub-domain URL is not working

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I've created sub-domain URL on my site but it always shows "page not found" error. When I write `foldername.website.com` so it shows page not found but it works when I write `website.com/foldername`. I've removed all code of .htaccess from main folder and sub folder but still sub-domain URL is not working.

Comment: How did you create subdomain? Can you show your `VirtualHost` entry?

Answer (score 0):

Your web folder design should be something like:

> website.com

```
/ <root> -----> <content for website>
```

> forum.website.com

```
/ <root> --------> <Content for subdomain website>
```

You really can not have a nested relationship for these two folders, like website folder cannot contain the subdomain folder; which looks to be the case here.

Comment: Yes its correct and I have created sub-folder under root directory only. As without it how I will create sub-domain url? Upto my thinking sub-domain url work for sub-folders. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: For subdomain URl, you need to configure a subdomain and point to a subdomain folder. Since you are able to access your subdomain with `website.com/subdomain` - it means your subdomain folder is logically a subdirectory of main domain folder.