# Need to redirect folders like sub-domain within same domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Currently my URL is like http://vidleap.com/nov5and151/index.html and now I want to redirect this URL like http://nov5and151.vidleap.com/index.html. So how to do it via htaccess?

I am using below code but it's not working.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?vidleap\.com [NC]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.*)?$ http://www.$1.vidleap.com$2 [R=301,L,NC]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)\.vidleap\.com [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Check your access logs file

Comment: What URLs are not working for you using these rules?

Comment: URL that is currently showing: http://vidleap.com/nov5and151/index.html and I need it to show like this: http://nov5and151.vidleap.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try these rules in different order:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
     Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.*)?$ http://www.$1.domain.com$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Actually this project is based on silex framework and angularjs so if I use above code then it converts all other urls for css, javascript and .html views files also so now project is not loading it as url is wrong now.

Comment: How to exclude folders where I do not want to apply this rewrite rule so I think it will work.

Comment: I need to change dimain.com to vidleap.com my domain name right? As I changed it before also.

Comment: But still its not working as my angular js state url is messed up now so project again is not loading.

Comment: Actually I think it will not be possible in this way. As there will be many folders under vidleap.com doamin and each domain contains a complete static site so is there any possibility that I can keep separate htaccess file in each site folder and once that folder call from vidleap.com url then we can apply this rewrite rule to make url for that site like I want?

Comment: I think you should edit the question and clarify these requirements with examples as it appears very confusing to me now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these :-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What is myfolder here as my folder name will be dynamic so will it work for dynamic folder also?

Comment: ok then remove that myfolder , i have edited code please try again

Comment: I have edited code again can you please try again using that.