# Need to redirect php page to html using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have read htacess condition from this url [Htacess Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342238/need-to-redirect-php-page-to-html-using-htaccess)

but can't understand how to solve the problem  when the condition is solve in htacess.

My main question is how to change the all php page into the html format any where to click the the PHP link then open the

**Just Like Example** : This php url any where to open that the redirect to the html page what i set the condition in htacess
PHP Url

http://www.localhost/efundoo.com/products.php?product=Touch-Screen-Digitizer-For-Videocon-A10

And change into the

http://www.localhost/efundoo/public_html/products/lcd-display-for-samsung-galaxy-star-pro-gt-s7262.html

My htacess condition is following

1) This is running fine

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1&type=$2  [NC,QSA]
```

2) but when i try this condition  Page are not open

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?user=([^\s&]+)&type=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^./]+)/.html$ page.php?user=$1&type=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: What does Page not open mean? Are you getting a 404 error ? please explain more, **your question is unclear** so far.

Comment: @Starkeen


How  can i redirect the php pages into the html page using the htacess  
If the URLs are coming from anywhere  the website and blogspot

Answer (score 1):

Try this in **`.htaccess`**,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**`.htaccess`** file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**`.html`** to **`.php`**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

**`.php`** to **`.html`**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301]
```

**`config.php`** file:

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; //specify your html file
```

Comment: Yes project is in CI. I am some php url post into the blog and now my site is fully html based. how to changed these php URLs into the html page using the htacess

Comment: I See this but can't solution

**Html & PHP Page both are open** I want one page open in site only html if user click the php file then open the HTML page  another wise html are automatically open

products.php?product=Full-Body-Panel-Nokia-1208-Mobile-Phone-Housing-Fascia-Faceplate